# Array of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR

Tags: arrays, vector, vhdl

I want to create an array that can hold std_logic_vectors as its elements, but im not sure how to place the elements into the array.

My code to create the array is the following:

```
type ist_array is array (0 to 1) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
```

I want to place 2 32-bit vectors into this array. The vectors are input ports.

But from here, im not sure what to do to place my vectors into the array.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why it got downvoted without an explanation.

The solution, which i found through just trial and debugging is:

```
type ist_array is array (0 to 1) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
variable Instructions: ist_array;
```

Where `ist_array` is the type of array i want to create and `Instructions` is the declaration of a variable which has type `ist_array`.

Then, to place a vector into this array i simply do:

```
Instructions(0) := a_vector(31 downto 0);
```